# Working with images of different file types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Please see the code below:

```
    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Image png = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\bert\\Desktop\\Images\\png.png");
                png.Save("C:\\Users\\bert\\Desktop\\Images\\png.jpg");

            }
        }

}
```

I realise the Image class can represent lots of different image types e.g. GIF, JPG, TIF etc.  Does this mean I can load any filetype into the image and then save it to the filesystem in any format I choose?

For example, load a .gif and then save a .jpg or load a png and save a .gif etc.

Comment: Is this the `System.Drawing.Image` class?

Comment: @gunr2171 , yes.  I am using .net core 2.1.

Comment: According to [the documentation for that method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_), you get an exception if "The image was saved with the wrong image format.". When you ran this code, did it save the file, and was it actually a jpg format or a png with a jpg extension?

Comment: @gunr2171, it worked for me.

Comment: There's multiple examples on that page of how to, for example, load a .bmp and save it as a .gif.

Comment: @gunr2171, agreed.  I will delete this question.  Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: It is not recommended to use System.Drawing on server apps.. it has tons of problems. Even the ASP.NET team goes about saying it out in the clear.. https://photosauce.net/blog/post/5-reasons-you-should-stop-using-systemdrawing-from-aspnet. You can use ImageSharp instead. Also here: https://youtu.be/PC7lnstHBBc?t=394